# How to highlight a label in Delphi when the mouse hovers over it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Which event do I use? And what do I say?

[image: events]

```
procedure TLogin.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
position:=poScreenCenter;
end;

procedure TLogin.lblHelpClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Help.Show;
end;

end.
```

Where do I use the code to highlight?

Comment: OnMouseEnter/Leave

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution as follows:

1. Set **Transparent** (Label Properties) = False
2. Label events:

   - **OnMouseEnter** (when you put the cursor on the label)
   - **OnMouseLeave** (when the cursor outside the label)

The code as bellow:

```
// On Mouse Enter
procedure TMainForm.lblNameMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
    lblName.Color := clRed; // assign color that you want
end;

// On Mouse Leave
procedure TMainForm.lblNameMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
    lblName.Color := clBtnFace; // assign default color
end;
```

Hope you can solve this problem soon.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help...<3